# Monaca (cordova) compiled Android app is unable to make AJAX requests

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, monaca

All ajax requests are getting executed properly when I use the monaca debugger app of either ios or android. They are also working fine with the ios app compiled using monaca build.

However the android app (compiled using monaca build) is just not able to make ajax requests (something like a CORS error).

I have the following

```
<access origin="*"/>   
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

lines in the config.xml file

and

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: content: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

in my index.html file

Can anyone suggest a fix for this pls?